# MomentJs create new date from string (italian format)

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to create a moment date in italian format (day/month/year).

I try this:

```
moment("07/03/2015","DD/MM/YYYY").toISOString()
```

and I would expect "2015-03-07"

but I get "2015-03-06T23:00:00.000Z".

Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because toISOString "Formats a string to the ISO8601 standard."

You should use `.format('YYY-MM-DD')` instead like:

```
moment("07/03/2015","DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Thank you Fred.
But I still don't understand this results:
moment("07/03/2015","DD/MM/YYYY").day() => 6 
moment("07/03/2015","DD/MM/YYYY").month() => 2

Comment: That's because these functions return the day of the week (Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6), and month (Months are zero indexed, so January is month 0), respectively.